# How to do XML-Split and Keep Parent Element?

Tags: spring-integration

I know Spring Integration is rather old but I have a piece of code that needs small modification to move on. I need to split the incoming XML message and preserve the parent node. Here is my XML:

```
<Order>
  <Item>A</Item>
  <Item>B</Item>
</Order>
```

And I want to split into 2 XMLs and preserve the XSD validation.

```
<Order>
 <Item>A</Item>
</Order>
```

and

```
<Order>
  <Item>B</Item>
</Order>
```

Did this:

```
<beans xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml">
...
<int-xml:xpath-splitter id="splitter">
<int-xml:xpath-expression expression="/Order/Item"/>
</int-xml:xpath-splitter>
...
```

It split into

```
<Item>A</Item>
```

and

```
<Item>B</Item>
```

but I need the parent to be there. Anyway to make it works? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please, elaborate more how that happened that Spring Integration project is old for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an `<int-xml:xslt-transformer>` after your `<int-xml:xpath-splitter>`.

See Reference Manual for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/xml.html#xml-xslt-payload-transformers

You need to learn what is XSLT and so on.

Comment: Works like a charm! I worked in XSLT for years but never did XML->XML. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

> I know Spring Integration is rather old

??

It is actively maintained and enhanced; there was a [completely new release this month](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/02/spring-integration-5-2-ga-available).

You either need a custom splitter, or you can add a transformer after the splitter to add the outer node.